# What gonna happen if two geth clients( in two different machines) running with the same nodekey file (node id) within the Mainnet?

Tags: nodes, ethereum, go-ethereum, geth

If someone copies the nodekey to another machine, and runs the geth with that key. Test it, just don't quite understand the underlying mech.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If two nodes are using the same node key, the network will only recognize one of them and only one of them will be able to broadcast to/work with the network.

While this is happening, the other one may be running and synced, but it will be "invisible" to the network.